# Clarification Needed on Derivation in Judea Pearl's "Detecting Latent Heterogeneity" (2015)

Tags: causality, structural-equation-modeling, counterfactuals

I'm reading a paper by Judea Pearl titled "Detecting Latent Heterogeneity" from 2015, which can be found at this link: [Detecting Latent Heterogeneity](https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r406.pdf)

I'm having trouble understanding a derivation in Appendix B of the paper. Here's the excerpt:

\begin{array}{ll}
M: \quad & Y=\beta X+\gamma Z+\delta X Z+\epsilon_1 \\
& X=\alpha Z+\epsilon_2 \\
& Z=\epsilon_3
\end{array}

\begin{aligned}
M_x: \quad & Y=\beta X+\gamma Z+\delta x Z+\epsilon_1 \\
& X=x \\
& Z=\epsilon_3
\end{aligned}

The paper goes on to compute conditional counterfactuals and states:

\begin{aligned}
& E T T=E\left[Y_x-Y_{x^{\prime}} \mid X=x\right] \\
& E T U=E\left[Y_x-Y_{x^{\prime}} \mid X=x^{\prime}\right]
\end{aligned}

The paper says that since $Y_x$ is equal to the solution for $Y$ in the mutilated model $M_x$, we have:

\begin{align}
E[Y_x | X=x'] &= E[\beta x + \gamma Z + \delta xZ + \epsilon_1 | X=x'] \nonumber \\
&= \beta x + (\gamma + \delta x) E[Z | X=x'] \nonumber
\end{align}

And then, the paper states:

$$E[Z | X=x'] = \alpha x'$$

This result is used to calculate $E[Y_x | X=x']$ as:

$$E[Y_x | X=x'] = \beta x + (\gamma + \delta x) \alpha x'$$

I'm having difficulty understanding why $E[Z|X=x']$ is equal to $\alpha x'$.

From the original model $M$, we have $X = \alpha Z + \epsilon_2$. When conditioned on $X = x'$, I would expect:

$$E[Z | X=x'] = \frac{x'}{\alpha}$$

Could someone please clarify why $E[Z|X=x']$ is stated to be $\alpha x'$ in the paper, and not the result I derived? Is there an underlying assumption or additional information that I'm missing?

Thank you.